# How to display custom message for (Genesis) featured posts if no posts

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets, genesis-theme-framework

I'm using the Genesis Framework, and the custom post types featured post widget (code below). I need to display a custom error message for a particular post type if there are no post present for that post type. Currently, the plugin displays nothing if there are no post, but still displays the widget title. I don't know where to begin.

```
<?php
/**
 * Genesis Featured Custom Post Type Widget
 *
 * @package GenesisFeaturedCustomPostTypeWidget
 * @author  StudioPress
 * @author  Jo Waltham
 * @license GPL-2.0+
 *
 */

 /**
 * Register Genesis Featured Custom Post Type Widget
 * 
 * @package GenesisFeaturedCustomPostTypeWidget
 * @author  StudioPress
 * @author  Jo Waltham
 */

 /**
* Please note that most of this code is from the Genesis Featured Post Widget included in the Genesis Framework.
* I have just added support for Custom Post Types
*/


class Genesis_Featured_Custom_Post_Type extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Holds widget settings defaults, populated in constructor.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $defaults;

    /**
     * Constructor. Set the default widget options and create widget.
     *
     * @since 0.1.8
     */
    function __construct() {

        $this->defaults = array(
            'title'                   => '',    
            'post_type'               => 'post',
            'posts_cat'               => '',
            'posts_num'               => 1,
            'posts_offset'            => 0,
            'orderby'                 => '',
            'order'                   => '',
            'exclude_displayed'       => 0,
            'show_image'              => 0,
            'image_alignment'         => '',
            'image_size'              => '',
            'show_gravatar'           => 0,
            'gravatar_alignment'      => '',
            'gravatar_size'           => '',
            'show_title'              => 0,
            'show_byline'             => 0,
            'post_info'               => '[post_date] ' . __( 'By', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ) . ' [post_author_posts_link] [post_comments]',
            'show_content'            => 'excerpt',
            'content_limit'           => '',
            'more_text'               => __( '[Read More...]', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ),
            'extra_num'               => '',
            'extra_title'             => '',
            'more_from_category'      => '',
            'more_from_category_text' => __( 'More Posts from this Category', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ),
        );

        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname'   => 'featured-content featuredpost',
            'description' => __( 'Displays featured custom post types with thumbnails', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ),
        );

        $control_ops = array(
            'id_base' => 'featured-custom-post-type',
            'width'   => 505,
            'height'  => 350,
        );

        parent::__construct( 'featured-custom-post-type', __( 'Genesis - Featured Custom Post Types', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ), $widget_ops, $control_ops );

    }

    /**
     * Echo the widget content.
     *
     * @since 0.1.8
     *
     * @param array $args Display arguments including before_title, after_title, before_widget, and after_widget.
     * @param array $instance The settings for the particular instance of the widget
     */
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        global $wp_query, $_genesis_displayed_ids;

        extract( $args );

        //* Merge with defaults
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $this->defaults );

        echo $before_widget;

        //* Set up the author bio
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) )
            echo $before_title . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base ) . $after_title;

        $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => $instance['post_type'],
            'cat'       => $instance['posts_cat'],
            'showposts' => $instance['posts_num'],
            'offset'    => $instance['posts_offset'],
            'orderby'   => $instance['orderby'],
            'order'     => $instance['order'],
        );

        //* Exclude displayed IDs from this loop?
        if ( $instance['exclude_displayed'] )
            $query_args['post__not_in'] = (array) $_genesis_displayed_ids;

        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            $_genesis_displayed_ids[] = get_the_ID();

            genesis_markup( array(
                'html5'   => '<article %s>',
                'xhtml'   => sprintf( '<div class="%s">', implode( ' ', get_post_class() ) ),
                'context' => 'entry',
            ) );

            $image = genesis_get_image( array(
                'format'  => 'html',
                'size'    => $instance['image_size'],
                'context' => 'featured-post-widget',
                'attr'    => genesis_parse_attr( 'entry-image-widget' ),
            ) );

            if ( $instance['show_image'] && $image )
                printf( '<a href="%s" title="%s" class="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink(), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), esc_attr( $instance['image_alignment'] ), $image );

            if ( ! empty( $instance['show_gravatar'] ) ) {
                echo '<span class="' . esc_attr( $instance['gravatar_alignment'] ) . '">';
                echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), $instance['gravatar_size'] );
                echo '</span>';
            }

            if ( $instance['show_title'] )
                echo genesis_html5() ? '<header class="entry-header">' : '';

                if ( ! empty( $instance['show_title'] ) ) {

                    if ( genesis_html5() )
                        printf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></h2>', get_permalink(), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), get_the_title() );
                    else
                        printf( '<h2><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></h2>', get_permalink(), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), get_the_title() );

                }

                if ( ! empty( $instance['show_byline'] ) && ! empty( $instance['post_info'] ) )
                    printf( genesis_html5() ? '<p class="entry-meta">%s</p>' : '<p class="byline post-info">%s</p>', do_shortcode( $instance['post_info'] ) );

            if ( $instance['show_title'] )
                echo genesis_html5() ? '</header>' : '';

            if ( ! empty( $instance['show_content'] ) ) {

                echo genesis_html5() ? '<div class="entry-content">' : '';

                if ( 'excerpt' == $instance['show_content'] ) {
                    the_excerpt();
                }
                elseif ( 'content-limit' == $instance['show_content'] ) {
                    the_content_limit( (int) $instance['content_limit'], esc_html( $instance['more_text'] ) );
                }
                else {

                    global $more;

                    $orig_more = $more;
                    $more = 0;

                    the_content( esc_html( $instance['more_text'] ) );

                    $more = $orig_more;

                }

                echo genesis_html5() ? '</div>' : '';

            }

            genesis_markup( array(
                'html5' => '</article>',
                'xhtml' => '</div>',
            ) );

        endwhile; endif;

        //* Restore original query
        wp_reset_query();

        //* The EXTRA Posts (list)
        if ( ! empty( $instance['extra_num'] ) ) {
            if ( ! empty( $instance['extra_title'] ) )
                echo $before_title . esc_html( $instance['extra_title'] ) . $after_title;

            $offset = intval( $instance['posts_num'] ) + intval( $instance['posts_offset'] );

            $query_args = array(
                'post_type' => $instance['post_type'],
                'cat'       => $instance['posts_cat'],
                'showposts' => $instance['extra_num'],
                'offset'    => $offset,
            );

            $wp_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

            $listitems = '';

            if ( have_posts() ) {
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post();
                    $_genesis_displayed_ids[] = get_the_ID();
                    $listitems .= sprintf( '<li><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></li>', get_permalink(), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), get_the_title() );
                }

                if ( mb_strlen( $listitems ) > 0 )
                    printf( '<ul>%s</ul>', $listitems );
            }

            //* Restore original query
            wp_reset_query();
        }

        if ( ! empty( $instance['more_from_category'] ) && ! empty( $instance['posts_cat'] ) )
            printf(
                '<p class="more-from-category"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a></p>',
                esc_url( get_category_link( $instance['posts_cat'] ) ),
                esc_attr( get_cat_name( $instance['posts_cat'] ) ),
                esc_html( $instance['more_from_category_text'] )
            );

        echo $after_widget;

    }

    /**
     * Update a particular instance.
     *
     * This function should check that $new_instance is set correctly.
     * The newly calculated value of $instance should be returned.
     * If "false" is returned, the instance won't be saved/updated.
     *
     * @since 0.1.8
     *
     * @param array $new_instance New settings for this instance as input by the user via form()
     * @param array $old_instance Old settings for this instance
     * @return array Settings to save or bool false to cancel saving
     */
    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

        $new_instance['title']     = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $new_instance['more_text'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['more_text'] );
        $new_instance['post_info'] = wp_kses_post( $new_instance['post_info'] );
        return $new_instance;

    }

    /**
     * Echo the settings update form.
     *
     * @since 0.1.8
     *
     * @param array $instance Current settings
     */
    function form( $instance ) {

        //* Merge with defaults
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $this->defaults );

        $args = array(
            'public' => true
        );
        $output = 'names';
        $operator = 'and';
        $post_type_list = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );


        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['title'] ); ?>" class="widefat" />
        </p>

        <div class="genesis-widget-column">

            <div class="genesis-widget-column-box genesis-widget-column-box-top">

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_type' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Post Type', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_type' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'post_type' ); ?>">

                        <?php
                        foreach ( $post_type_list as $post_type_item ) 
                            echo '<option style="padding-right:10px;" value="'. esc_attr( $post_type_item ) .'" '. selected( esc_attr( $post_type_item ), $instance['post_type'], false ) .'>'. esc_attr( $post_type_item ) .'</option>'; 

                        echo '<option style="padding-right:10px;" value="any" '. selected( 'any', $instance['post_type'], false ) .'>'. __( 'any', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ) .'</option>'; 
                        ?>          
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'posts_cat' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Category', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <?php
                    $categories_args = array(
                        'name'            => $this->get_field_name( 'posts_cat' ),
                        'selected'        => $instance['posts_cat'],
                        'orderby'         => 'Name',
                        'hierarchical'    => 1,
                        'show_option_all' => __( 'All Categories', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ),
                        'hide_empty'      => '0',
                    );
                    wp_dropdown_categories( $categories_args ); ?>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'posts_num' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of Posts to Show', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'posts_num' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'posts_num' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['posts_num'] ); ?>" size="2" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'posts_offset' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of Posts to Offset', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'posts_offset' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'posts_offset' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['posts_offset'] ); ?>" size="2" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'orderby' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Order By', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'orderby' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'orderby' ); ?>">
                        <option value="date" <?php selected( 'date', $instance['orderby'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Date', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="title" <?php selected( 'title', $instance['orderby'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Title', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="parent" <?php selected( 'parent', $instance['orderby'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Parent', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="ID" <?php selected( 'ID', $instance['orderby'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'ID', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="comment_count" <?php selected( 'comment_count', $instance['orderby'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Comment Count', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="rand" <?php selected( 'rand', $instance['orderby'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Random', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'order' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Sort Order', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'order' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'order' ); ?>">
                        <option value="DESC" <?php selected( 'DESC', $instance['order'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Descending (3, 2, 1)', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="ASC" <?php selected( 'ASC', $instance['order'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Ascending (1, 2, 3)', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'exclude_displayed' ); ?>" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'exclude_displayed' ); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $instance['exclude_displayed'] ); ?>/>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'exclude_displayed' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Exclude Previously Displayed Posts?', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></label>
                </p>

            </div>

            <div class="genesis-widget-column-box">

                <p>
                    <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_gravatar' ); ?>" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_gravatar' ); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $instance['show_gravatar'] ); ?>/>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_gravatar' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show Author Gravatar', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></label>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'gravatar_size' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Gravatar Size', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'gravatar_size' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'gravatar_size' ); ?>">
                        <option value="45" <?php selected( 45, $instance['gravatar_size'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Small (45px)', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="65" <?php selected( 65, $instance['gravatar_size'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Medium (65px)', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="85" <?php selected( 85, $instance['gravatar_size'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Large (85px)', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="125" <?php selected( 105, $instance['gravatar_size'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Extra Large (125px)', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'gravatar_alignment' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Gravatar Alignment', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'gravatar_alignment' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'gravatar_alignment' ); ?>">
                        <option value="alignnone">- <?php _e( 'None', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?> -</option>
                        <option value="alignleft" <?php selected( 'alignleft', $instance['gravatar_alignment'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Left', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="alignright" <?php selected( 'alignright', $instance['gravatar_alignment'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Right', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                    </select>
                </p>

            </div>

            <div class="genesis-widget-column-box">

                <p>
                    <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_image' ); ?>" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_image' ); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $instance['show_image'] ); ?>/>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_image' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show Featured Image', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></label>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image_size' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Image Size', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image_size' ); ?>" class="genesis-image-size-selector" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image_size' ); ?>">
                        <option value="thumbnail">thumbnail (<?php echo get_option( 'thumbnail_size_w' ); ?>x<?php echo get_option( 'thumbnail_size_h' ); ?>)</option>
                        <?php
                        $sizes = genesis_get_additional_image_sizes();
                        foreach( (array) $sizes as $name => $size )
                            echo '<option value="'.esc_attr( $name ).'" '.selected( $name, $instance['image_size'], FALSE ).'>'.esc_html( $name ).' ( '.$size['width'].'x'.$size['height'].' )</option>';
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image_alignment' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Image Alignment', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image_alignment' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image_alignment' ); ?>">
                        <option value="alignnone">- <?php _e( 'None', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?> -</option>
                        <option value="alignleft" <?php selected( 'alignleft', $instance['image_alignment'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Left', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="alignright" <?php selected( 'alignright', $instance['image_alignment'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Right', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                    </select>
                </p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="genesis-widget-column genesis-widget-column-right">

            <div class="genesis-widget-column-box genesis-widget-column-box-top">

                <p>
                    <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_title' ); ?>" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_title' ); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $instance['show_title'] ); ?>/>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show Post Title', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></label>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_byline' ); ?>" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_byline' ); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $instance['show_byline'] ); ?>/>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_byline' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show Post Info', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'post_info' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'post_info' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['post_info'] ); ?>" class="widefat" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_content' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Content Type', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_content' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_content' ); ?>">
                        <option value="content" <?php selected( 'content', $instance['show_content'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Show Content', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="excerpt" <?php selected( 'excerpt', $instance['show_content'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Show Excerpt', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="content-limit" <?php selected( 'content-limit', $instance['show_content'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'Show Content Limit', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                        <option value="" <?php selected( '', $instance['show_content'] ); ?>><?php _e( 'No Content', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'content_limit' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Limit content to', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>
                        <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image_alignment' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'content_limit' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( intval( $instance['content_limit'] ) ); ?>" size="3" />
                        <?php _e( 'characters', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>
                    </label>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'more_text' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'More Text (if applicable)', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'more_text' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'more_text' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['more_text'] ); ?>" />
                </p>

            </div>

            <div class="genesis-widget-column-box">

                <p><?php _e( 'To display an unordered list of more posts from this category, please fill out the information below', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'extra_title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'extra_title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'extra_title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['extra_title'] ); ?>" class="widefat" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'extra_num' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of Posts to Show', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'extra_num' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'extra_num' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['extra_num'] ); ?>" size="2" />
                </p>

            </div>

            <div class="genesis-widget-column-box">

                <p>
                    <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'more_from_category' ); ?>" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'more_from_category' ); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( $instance['more_from_category'] ); ?>/>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'more_from_category' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show Category Archive Link', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?></label>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'more_from_category_text' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Link Text', 'genesis-featured-custom-post-type-widget' ); ?>:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'more_from_category_text' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'more_from_category_text' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $instance['more_from_category_text'] ); ?>" class="widefat" />
                </p>

            </div>

        </div>
        <?php

    }

}
```

Comment: Surely you can narrow this down a bit? That is a huge, huge block of code to dig through.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is solved yet since the post is so old, but you'll probably have to edit this file (non-upgrade safe manner) in order to do it. Try doing what this guy recommends: [Show default content if custom WP_Query has no posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70651/show-default-content-if-custom-wp-query-has-no-posts)

Basically, create an `else` statement where the code you pasted above says `endif; endwhile;`.